# javafx variables transfer between two controller (set and get data in different controller) - Updated

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am trying to  transfer  variable from one controller to another but i am not getting correct output:

**My codes:**

```
   public class CustomControl extends AnchorPane implements Initializable {
    String customId;

    public CustomControl() {
        //if you want to set a FXML
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/res/customControl.fxml"));
        //Defines this class as the controller
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        //this.getStylesheets().add("/res/style.css"); <- if you want to set a css
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }

    }
        public String getCustomId() {
            return customId;
        }
    public void setCustomId(String customId) {
        return this.customId = customId;
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
          //Initializes the controller
    }
}
```

To set CustomId variable at other controller

```
CustomControl c = new CustomControl();
c.setCustomId("StackOverflow");
```

To get CustomId variable from other controller

```
CustomControl c = new CustomControl();
c.getCustomId();
System.out.Println(c.getCustomId());
```

It gives me output

`null`

but required is

`StackOverflow`

Comment: When you create the second instance of `CustomControl`, you don't call `setCustomId(...)` on it.

Comment: no it is already set in different controller. Is it not possible.

Comment: `CustomControl c = new CustomControl();
c.getCustomId();` Clearly the `customId` has not been set, so it is `null`.

Comment: so what should i do get desired output.

Comment: `CustomControl c = new CustomControl();
c.setCustomId("StackOverflow");
//...
System.out.println(c.getCustomId());`

Comment: but i want to set CustomId in different controller and get CustomId in different controller is this possible.

Comment: Then this is exactly the same question as you asked yesterday, and, as yesterday, the solution is in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml

Comment: but it shows same error

Comment: given URL is too much confusing can it be explained in simple way.

Comment: please can you help me with a new example

Comment: help me please @James_D

Comment: The answer is already provided. That answer describes most of the ways (including the easiest ways) to solve your problem. If you don't understand that answer, consider reading some intro Java tutorials or taking an intro course somewhere.

Comment: i am able to understand that but can't adjust it in my codes because i am new in javafx

Comment: help me please @James_D